# Visual studio custom code snippet not working in parameter list in method definition

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I've implemented a custom code snippet (for visual studio) ([code snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2019)).

I have the problem that I cannot use this code snippet in the parameter list in the method definition

Here is the custom code snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>XXX</Title>
      <Author>XXX</Author>
      <Description>XXX</Description>
      <Shortcut>tmtr</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="CSharp" Kind="method body/method decl/type decl/page/file/any">
        <![CDATA[string out]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

E.g. here

```
public void myMethod(string in, /*tmtr does not work here when I press tab So the desired code is not displayed*/)
{
    // 
}
```

I tried all `Kind` values and none of them solved the problem

Any ideas?

Comment: I imported this snippet and it worked exactly as I expected it to...

That said, you can't name parameters "in" or "out"—those are keywords. Is that your problem? (Or did you mean "in string" and "out string"?)

Comment: does this also work in the parameter list in the method definition?I also used in and out only as an example here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

After you type “tmtr”, you need to press tab twice, as once for Visual Basic, twice for C#. You could refer to this official document: [Description and shortcut fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019#description-and-shortcut-fields)(Walkthrough: Create a code snippet), and step 7 mentioned this.

If this still doesn’t work, not sure if you miss some steps to create a snippet, please [follow/check the steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019) below.

1. Create a new XML and add the template in VS.
2. Save the snippet anywhere you want as XXX.snippet.
3. Open Code Snippets Manager from Tools > Code Snippets Manager.
4. Click Import button and browse the location where you saved the code snippet in the previous procedure, select it and click Open.
5. In the Import Code Snippet dialog, you could choose My Code Snippets, select it and click Finish, then OK.
6. You could then test it by typing “tmtr” and press Tab twice.

Comment: thank you for your help. I actually only have to press the tab once, not twice, and that works e.g. in the method body but not in the parameter list in the method definition